# Dynamic attribute lookup in java

Tags: java, reflection

Python has a way to dynamically find and retrieve an object attribute using hasattr and getarr:

```
try:
    if hasattr(obj,name)
      thing = getattr(obj, name)
  except AttributeError:
    pass
  else:
    break
```

What would be the most efficient(coding and performance) way to achieve this java?
I would be serializing instances of a class  - and over time ,attributes may get added to the class.
So,on retrieval,I should be able to hand out a getAttribute-styled API to client - and return the attribute only if that particular version supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using reflection to get the field, make it accessible (in case it's private or otherwise not accessible from the current scope), and get its value with relation to the object in question.

```
public static Object getAttribute(Object obj, String name) throws Exception {
    Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(obj);
}
```

A [`NoSuchFieldException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldException.html) will be thrown in the event that no field exists called `name`.

Comment: Cool. This is much more efficient and your comment about "not particularly efficient" no longer applies. :-)

Comment: probably good to note that setAccessible means if it's private/protected it will become public

Answer (score 1):

Vulcan's answer is correct, but another option is to use [Apache's BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).  For example, given the class:

```
public class Employee {
    public Address getAddress(String type);
    public void setAddress(String type, Address address);
    public Employee getSubordinate(int index);
    public void setSubordinate(int index, Employee subordinate);
    public String getFirstName();
    public void setFirstName(String firstName);
    public String getLastName();
    public void setLastName(String lastName);
}
```

You can do:

```
Employee employee = ...;
String firstName = (String) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(employee, "firstName");
String lastName = (String) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(employee, "lastName");
... manipulate the values ...
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(employee, "firstName", firstName);
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(employee, "lastName", lastName);
```

Or:

```
DynaBean wrapper = new WrapDynaBean(employee);
String firstName = wrapper.get("firstName");
```

There are lots of other ways of accessing beans as well, like creating a `Map` of properties to values.  See the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard) for more examples.

Comment: I assume this just uses Reflection under the hood